# How can a filter a data extension

Tags: marketing-cloud

We are currently running a Campaign that will last 10 days. We are now looking to send another email to this same data extension but want it to go to only people who have received the first email. How can I filter the data extension to allow me to see and send to contacts that have received this certain email.

Comment: query the records based on jobid

Answer (score 1):

You can use one of these two options:

1- On the Tracking tab, you can see the jobID of the email you sent. When you enter it, you can click on the number of people who got the email to export them as a .csv file. You can put those people into a data extension and send to them.

2- You can query based on the jobID from SendLog as pkharries said. You can see the example below:

```
SELECT EmailAddress, SubscriberKey 

FROM _Sent 

WHERE JobID = YOURJOBID
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a Measure using the jobID or email name and based on the Event Source 'Sent'. Then you can apply the measure in a filter to exclude or include that people from the new target.